# Alphanumeric RegEx validation

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation

What is the regular Expression Validation for only Letters and Numbers in asp.net?

I need to enter first two should be character after that it can take hyphen(`-`), space(), apostrophes(`'`)

I tried

```
^[A-Z a-z\s-'\s]{2,25}$
```

this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want, this should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[-\040']*$
```

This will match two letters followed by any number of hyphens, spaces, or apostrophes. It will match the following strings

```
ab --
xy'
zz
```

But will not match these

```
12
'ab
x-
```

*NOTE:* This will not limit the length of the match expression (as your original one did). If that's important replace the `*` with `{,23}`.